# belle-sip linphone yocto integration

Tags: yocto

Found Zlib: /belle-sip/git_d8c5e9e08b3bd6640898e46850333f1ad900c8d2-r0.0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include
| CMake Error /belle-sip/git_d8c5e9e08b3bd6640898e46850333f1ad900c8d2-r0.0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
|   Could NOT find Antlr3 (missing: ANTLR3_COMMAND)
| Call Stack (most recent call first):
|   /recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
|   cmake/FindAntlr3.cmake:80 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
|   CMakeLists.txt:82 (find_package)
|
|
| -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Any pointers on this

bb file

```html
require belle-sip.inc

inherit gitpkgv

PR = "${INC_PR}.0"

python () {
    if d.getVar('LATEST_REVISIONS', True) == "1":
        d.setVar('SRCREV', '${AUTOREV}')
    else:
        d.setVar('SRCREV', 'd8c5e9e08b3bd6640898e46850333f1ad900c8d2')
}

# For visualisation
python () {
    print("")
    print("belle-sip")
    print(d.getVar('SRCREV', True))
}

#SRCREV = "c840e2192b2d0151cc895b844e44bfe0d2103fcf"
SRC_URI = "git://git.linphone.org/BC/public/belle-sip.git;commit=${SRCREV}"
PV = "git_${SRCREV}"
PKGV = "${GITPKGVTAG}"
```

Comment: Please provide your Yocto recipe that is failing.

Comment: inc file  EPENDS = "libantlr3c-bc bctoolbox zlib"
PROVIDES = "libbellesip"
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"


inherit  pkgconfig cmake gettext


EXTRA_OECMAKE += " -DENABLE_STRICT=NO -DCMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH=ON"
EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-DJava_JAVA_EXECUTABLE=${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java"
EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR=share -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=lib"
ANTLR_CFLAGS += " -I ${STAGING_DIR_HOST}/usr/include"
ANTLR_LIBS += " -L ${STAGING_DIR_HOST}/usr/lib"
CFLAGS += " ${ANTLR_CFLAGS} ${ANTLR_LIBS} -lantlr3c"

Comment: Are you using this layer https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/meta-bc ? I tried to create the build and didn't know which layer you are using, please provide more info: the layers (bblayers.conf), the build branch (zeus, sumo, ...), so I can reproduce the issue

Comment: yes,, https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/meta-bc.git with master branch and trying to bitbake linphone

Comment: This layer is too old and depends on many other layers, I didn't manage to create a simple build with it. Either you provide your build configuration steps and layers to reproduce this and help you or it is hard to find the issue.